# Elements in HTML/CSS move when I resize browser :(

Tags: html, css, styles, display

I tried changing the position to absolute, fixed and static. But, still get the same result.

I have also tried wrapping it in a div element, but I might've done it wrong so I would appreciate help with that. (If this is the solution)

The .table is not the only element that moves around, but I am hoping once I figure out a fix for one, it will apply to them all.

I want the elements to remain in the spot I place them in, and if anything shrink a bit.

This is the object I am trying to get to stay in one place.

This is my first time using html & css, so I would appreciate any help I could get.

Thanks for your time :)

```css
.table {
  font-family: "Fira Sans", sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 520px;
  width: 425px;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  z-index: 6;
  left: 120rem;
  bottom: 90rem;
  background-color: white;
  border: 4px solid black;
  z-index: 5;
}
```

```html
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <input type="text" class="search-input" placeholder="Abbreviation">
      </th>
      <th>
        <input type="text" class="search-input" placeholder="Full Name">
      </th>
      <th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>XXX</td>
      <td>XXX, XXX, XXX</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Sabrina, welcome.  First thing, what you have there is a CSS rule.  CSS rules apply to HTML elements.  You should post the associated element so I and others can better understand what is "in play" so to speak on your page.  Obviously remove content not intended for public consumption.

Comment: Hi! Just updated it, thanks.

Comment: Your HTML has problems. Please use a good editor or run it through a validator. You have unclosed elements and extra tags.

Comment: Just ran it through an editor and fixed all the problems, but still having issues resizing.

Comment: Your snippet shows me a polar bear in a snowstorm. I.e. I see nothing

Answer (score 0):

I've taken the liberty of modifying your html.  I've added some elements and reworked your css so as to help you understand how styles can affect one another.  your initial `.table` css contained too many rules that redefined what a `table` element is.  Hopefully my changes will help you gain some insights.

Also you should find an online resource to help with HTML and CSS.
[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) is **THE** source for web development.

#### ADDENDUM:

---

The nice thing about HTML and CSS is that they allow you to mix and match elements and rules. We have many tools to customize the look and feel of a page.  But this is also the bane of our existence.

FWIW: Just because we *can* embed data collection into a table (in the header or otherwise) doesn't mean we should.

Yes, it's legal.  Yes, it'll work.

But...it alters the HTML definition.  Which is again perfectly legal and it'll work. Until it doesn't.  Like using CSS to redefine a `display:table` to `display:block`

Then there is the matter of accessibility concerns, like screen readers finding inputs where it's expecting column headers

The various components of an element are designed to work together and should only be redefined with care.  Chances are if we find ourselves trying to make one element work like another, we missed something.

```css
.outer {
  position: relative;
}

.dontmove {
  position: absolute;
  width: 500px;
}

.table {
  font-family: "Fira Sans", sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  background-color: white;
  border: 4px solid black;
  width: 100%
}

.table th,
.table td {
  padding: 2px 6px;
}

.table th>input {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="dontmove">
    <table class="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>
            <input type="text" class="search-input" placeholder="Abbreviation">
          </th>
          <th>
            <input type="text" class="search-input" placeholder="Full Name">
          </th>
          <th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>XXX</td>
          <td>XXX, XXX, XXX</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for fixing up my code. I appreciate it. It did fix a few problems I was having, like ridding of the white space below. However, when I load the website on a smaller screen, a part of the table is still out of view.

Comment: well, your original post said you were trying to keep a table in fixed position and it seemed like you did not want the table to resize with the window.  In the CSS above try altering `.dontmove` class to `position: relative;` and `width: 100%;`

Comment: You should familiarize yourself with [Codepen](https://codepen.io/pen/).  It's great for kind of experimenting.

Comment: my apologies, I do want it to stay in a certain position, and it does with the relative positioning. However, it still does not resize when I switch browsers. The background image does resize, but the objects on top do not.

Comment: Ill check Codepen out!

Comment: what objects?  Your HTML shows only a table. Cross browser compatibility is a long standing problem, but it's much better now than it used to be.  If cross browser compatibility is paramount, consider implementing Bootstrap.